# Moving from a one-to-one relationship into a many-to-many relationship in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, relational-database

Like the title says, I want to move from a one-to-one relationship into a many-to-many relationship in my rails 3 app.

I'm fairly good with rails now but I lack a good understanding of databases and migrations.

Currently, I have a Project and User model. A Project belongs_to a User and a User has_many Projects.
I want to move into a situation where a project can have many users collaborating on it at once.

I'm pretty sure I need to set up a has_many :through type of relationship, but I am also curious as to how I can migrate all of my existing projects and users into this type of system.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need another table that links the two tables together.  This is how to support many to many relationships.

e.g.  Say you have two tables like this:

```
Projects
----------
projectid
{other columns}    

Users
-------
userid
{other columns}
```

The new table will look something like this:
    New Table

```
Projects_Users
--------------
projectid
userid
```

Now you can add another user to a project by simply adding the userid and projectid to
the Projects_Users table.  Similarly you will be able to add several users to the one project in the same table.

The primary key on that table is the composite key projectid & userid.

Comment: Right, I have the relationship set up now. How do I migrate all of my existing projects and users into this new format?

Answer (score 0):

> *Right, I have the relationship set up now. How do I migrate all of my existing projects and users into this new <strike>format</strike> table ?*

Well, it depends on how you have set the tables up now; how the two existing relations are implemented; where the `ProjectUser` data is sitting in the old table.  Post your DDL. You should be able to simply `INSERT ProjectUser SELECT FROM ...`.  We need to complete that FROM.

Also the number of rows is relevant; if it is large, you may have to break it into batches.

Comment: Ok sounds good, my tables have about a few thousand rows right now. I'm using sqlite3, not sure if that's what you mean by DDL (again, I have limited database knowledge)

Comment: @Matt. Few thousand is very small. Data Definition Language means your CREATE TABLE & INDEX statements, to complete the above command.

Comment: @Matt. Any chance of progressing this question/answer ?

Comment: Hey sorry about that, I got it working by putting a simple loop in a migration and assigned the values I needed in that loop. Thanks for your help though!